# Getting flickr images from short urls

Tags: api, flickr

For example if you have the following short flickr url: http://flic.kr/p/dnUvGp

How can you get the image url of the image shared by the link? (Without sending multiple requests)

For instagram you can just add `media/?size=l` to the url, and you get the image. Is there such a trick for flickr instead of using the API?

Answer (score 0):

The short photo id is a base58 conversion of the photo id, but it does not include the photo owner. So whilst you could calculate the short link, given a long link, the reverse is not true without going via the API (or URL redirection).